# Drilling deep into JSON file with Gson JsonReader

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonreader

I'm working with JsonReader for the first time and I'm trying to grab values within an array. Basically what I've found is to drill deep down into a JSON file it seems like there is a ton of repetition and loops. Surely there is a better way to do this? This looks plain awful. Is there a way to read and access (for example the DocumentList array) things directly? I'm convinced I don't know what I'm doing when I look at the mess below.

Is there a way to simply just loop through the documents objects and grab the required values, do work, them move to the next documents object?

```
      streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
      jsonReader = new JsonReader(streamReader);
      jsonReader.beginObject();
      while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
          final String name = jsonReader.nextName();
          if ("Level1".equals(name)) {
              jsonReader.beginObject();
              while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                  final String listName = jsonReader.nextName();
                  if ("DocumentList".equals(listName)) {
                      jsonReader.beginArray();
                      while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                          jsonReader.beginObject();
                          while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                              final String key = jsonReader.nextName();
                              if ("Documents".equals(key)) {
                                  jsonReader.beginObject();
                                  while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                                      final String fieldKey = jsonReader.nextName();
                                      if ("ID".equals(fieldKey)) {
                                        report.id = jsonReader.nextString();
                                      } 
                                      else if ("CName".equals(fieldKey)) {
                                        report.CName = jsonReader.nextString();
                                      } 
                                      else if ("Ext".equals(fieldKey)) {
                                        report.Ext = jsonReader.nextString();
                                      } 
                                      else {
                                        jsonReader.skipValue();
                                      }
                                  }
                                  jsonReader.endObject();

                                  //DO work on report (contents of "Documents")
                              } 
                              else {
                                jsonReader.skipValue();
                              }
                          }
                          jsonReader.endObject();
                      }
                      jsonReader.endArray();
                  } 
                  else {
                    jsonReader.skipValue();
                  }
              }
              jsonReader.endObject();
          } 
          else {
            jsonReader.skipValue();
          }
      }
      jsonReader.endObject();
```

Here is the sample JSON format that im working with

```
{
  "Level1": {
    "DocumentList": [
      {
        "Documents": {
          "ID": "123",
          "CName": "name",
          "SecurityStatus": "P",
          "Ext": "abc",
          "Prefix": "pre",
        }
      },
      {
        "Documents": {
          "ID": "321",
          "CName": "name2",
          "SecurityStatus": "Q",
          "Ext": "bca",
          "Prefix": "post",
        }
      },
            {
        "Documents": {
          "ID": "456",
          "CName": "name3",
          "SecurityStatus": "S",
          "Ext": "def",
          "Prefix": "dur",
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend defining classes for the objects in your JSON file. Then use any of the techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) to parse directly into a class-based data structure.

Comment: Defining classes to simply get the values of Json objects in an array seems like a lot of extra steps. Im basically converting the code from using org.json.JSONObjects to instead stream the data using gson.JSONReader If i can simply access the required data in a few lines of code using org.json.JSONObjects, it should be fairly staright forward to stream it as well, no? Im clearly missing something here.

Comment: You might want to try [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)